# Receiving JSON String Using Volley

Tags: android, json, node.js, mongodb, android-volley

My Node.js server sends an array consisting of JSON documents from MongoDB, but my Android app won't download it. I sent it using `response.send(placearray);.` However, if I send a plain string like `Request received`, it works perfectly.

I used a POST request sender to test the server, and it receives the array just fine, but Volley won't.

I understand the fact that I'm receiving it in a string may be causing this, but I don't know what to do.

Here is the procedure I used:

```
StringRequest PlaceRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new      Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            DisplayHotels(response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }) {
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> PlaceMap = new HashMap<>();
            PlaceMap.put("Test", "Test");
            return PlaceMap;
        }
    };
    PlaceQueue.add(PlaceRequest);
```

As Fakher suggested, I just tried this, but it still isn't working:

```
    JsonArrayRequest PlaceArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            ArrayList MArrList = new ArrayList();
            //MArrList.add(response);
            DisplayHotels(response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            Toast VerrorToast = Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }) {
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> PMap = new HashMap<>();
            PMap.put("Hotels", "All");
            return PMap;
        }
    };
```

It now receives the JSONArray, but it won't parse it, and this is the code I tried:

RequestQueue PlaceQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

```
    JsonArrayRequest PlaceArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            int i;
            ArrayList<String> MArrList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray ConvertedJarray = response.getJSONArray(i);
                        JSONObject PlaceParser = ConvertedJarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        MArrList.add(PlaceParser.get("PlaceName").toString());
                            MArrList.add(response.get(i).toString());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
```

I get this error: org.json.JSONException: Value {"_id":"55f97b849b8385cd03730b09","PlaceName":"W South Beach","PlaceType":"Hotel","PlaceAddress":"2201 Collins Avenue, Miami Beach, Florida, United States. Zip code: 33139.","PlaceCity":"Miami","EstimatedPrice":"2023","OtherDetails":"Cool Corner Suite.\nPanoramic ocean view.\nVIP amenities.\nRoom size: 1,350 sq ft (125 sq metres).\nNo smoking.\n"} at 108 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you are describing the problem, but it will speed up a solution if you put the complete volley code in your Q too. (onResponce) is just a part of volley

Comment: You should override getBody() instead of getParams()

Answer (score 0):

to get the array data with Volley you must JsonArrayRequest:

```
JsonArrayRequest newsReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


            }
        });
        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(newsReq);
```

here is a good [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) on using volley library

Comment: ok can you run the url that gives you the Json result on a browser and put the result please. It must begin and end with [ ].

Comment: Ok can you do some Log in your code ??
just Log the Json response so we can know wjere's the problem

Comment: Thank you. The problem has been resolved. I used the JsonObject class to parse the data in the ArrayList, and it works properly now.